# UICollectionView Segue Signal SIGBRT

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3

I made a manual Segue to a Collection View Controller but there is a error.

This is the segue code.

```
func showChatViewController() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toChatLogController", sender: self)
}
```

Yes it is very very basic

but there is error like this

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception  
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-mj8-fl-tie" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UICollectionView.'
```

Comment: Can you please add the code, so that I can tell you what went wrong?

Comment: Make sure the view controller that you have created the segue to is a collectionViewController and it has a collectionView as it's root view.